# No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'auto'

Tags: android, xml, compilation

So i'm getting this error now :

packages/apps/ROMControl/../../../external/jbirdvegas/mGerrit/res/drawable/commit_card_background_states_dark.xml:24: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'auto'

Before my second compile aokp compile the error was something like : 
packages/apps/ROMControl/../../../external/jbirdvegas/mGerrit/res/drawable/commit_card_background_states_dark.xml:24: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit'

I made these changes, as instructed. 
Change :
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit"
to :
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/auto"

But now the first error pops up. Any ideas ?

Comment: have you build your project again ?

Comment: Yes. A few times actually. It always stops there